# JSON:API ответы

Tags: javascript, node.js, content-type, json-api

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть задание. "Объекты ошибок должны быть возвращены в виде массива с ключом errors на верхнем уровне документа JSON:API."
Однако не понимаю как передать данные с массива. Массив отправляется с помощью:

```js
return res.status(checkErrorCode('VALIDATING')).send({ ... })
```

Совершенно не понимаю как передать эти данные и куда.
Content-Type и Accept заданы.

Comment: На каком языке программирования вы пишете? [Укажите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1441553/edit) в метах в вопросе.

Comment: Добавил, спасибо